# angular-dialogs-service scoping doesn't seem to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get angular-dialogs-service creating a custom dialog, it works and shows with this code:

```
  opts =
    keyboard: false
    backdrop: "static"
    size: "sm"

  dialogs.create "modals/error.html", "errorController", {message: "Hello!"}, opts
```

In my error.html I have this, in an attempt to get my message to show:

```
<div class="modal-body text-danger">
  <p>{{data.message}}</p>
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <p>{{$parent.message}}</p>
  <p>{{$parent.data.message}}</p>
</div>
```

none of these show the message, from what I can gather from the source and examples, data.message *should* work.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: I'm sure you've done this, but make sure your message that you're passing has a value. Try sending something static like `{message: "Hello"}`

Comment: Yeah, I have, nothing works :( Will have to spend some time debugging dialogs-service code I think!

Answer (score 1):

So I found my problem, the data passed to the dialogs service is not automatically assigned on the scope anywhere, in the example, which I missed, the controller for the dialog actually has the data injected, then assigns it on the scope.

```
MyApp.controller "errorController", ($scope, data) ->
  $scope.data = data
```

This has fixed my issue as you'd expect!

The way to bind to it, therefore is {{data.message}}